# Why dh_make doesn't provide all options for create skeleton for new package?

Tags: package-management, dh-make

I'm using:

- Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.
- dh-make package with version **2.201605~xenial1**

When I try to start packaging, dh_make propose next options:

```
$ dh_make
Type of package: (single, indep, library, python)
[s/i/l/p]?
```

I have downloaded dh_make sources. In the **lib** directory i found next subdirs

```
debian  debiani  debianl  debianm  debianp  debians  emacs  licenses  native
```

As I can understand **debianm** contain overrides for **multiple binnary** package type. But **dh_make** has no option for use it. Man page for **dh_make** also doesn't contain information about -m option.

Additionally, man page and `dh_make -h` command are not providing information for all licenses that exist in `lib/licenses`

Does anybody know is this a bug?

Is there any other way to use full features of **dh_make** script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a bug but a feature.
See https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dh-make/2.201602
Which breaks most of the HOWTOs - thanks Debian.